# Direct3D 11: Почему не отображается треугольник в 3D пространстве?

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d

Я изменил код из http://www.directxtutorial.com/Lesson.aspx?lessonid=11-4-5 в код, где треугольник должен был отображаться как бы в 3D пространстве. То есть просто добавил три матрицы: мира, вида и проекции. Эти матрицы передаются через константный буфер вершинному шейдеру. В вершинном шейдере просто происходит применение (умножение друг на друга) этих матриц, для имитации 3D мира.

Моя программа выполняется без ошибок, только треугольник по каким-то причинам не отображается. Скажите, может я пропустил какие-то обязательные требования или что-то не так с расчётами? Почему не отображается треугольник?

*My Game.cpp*

```
// include the basic windows header files and the Direct3D header files
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3dx11.h>
#include <d3dx10.h>
#include <xnamath.h>

// include the Direct3D Library file
#pragma comment (lib, "d3d11.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx11.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx10.lib")

// define the screen resolution
#define SCREEN_WIDTH  800
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 600

// global declarations
IDXGISwapChain* swapchain;             // the pointer to the swap chain interface
ID3D11Device* dev;                     // the pointer to our Direct3D device interface
ID3D11DeviceContext* devcon;           // the pointer to our Direct3D device context
ID3D11RenderTargetView* backbuffer;    // the pointer to our back buffer
ID3D11InputLayout* pLayout;            // the pointer to the input layout
ID3D11VertexShader* pVS;               // the pointer to the vertex shader
ID3D11PixelShader* pPS;                // the pointer to the pixel shader
ID3D11Buffer* pVBuffer;                // the pointer to the vertex buffer
ID3D11Buffer* pIBuffer;
ID3D11Buffer* wvpConstBuffer;
ID3D11DepthStencilView* pDepthBuffer;

// a struct to define a single vertex
struct VERTEX { FLOAT X, Y, Z; D3DXCOLOR Color; };

struct ConstantBuffer
{
    XMMATRIX mWorld;
    XMMATRIX mView;
    XMMATRIX mProjection;
};

XMMATRIX g_World;
XMMATRIX g_View;
XMMATRIX g_Projection;

// function prototypes
void InitD3D(HWND hWnd);    // sets up and initializes Direct3D
void RenderFrame(void);     // renders a single frame
void CleanD3D(void);        // closes Direct3D and releases memory
void InitGraphics(void);    // creates the shape to render
void InitPipeline(void);    // loads and prepares the shaders

// the WindowProc function prototype
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);


// the entry point for any Windows program
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hWnd;
    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.lpszClassName = L"WindowClass";

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    RECT wr = { 0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT };
    AdjustWindowRect(&wr, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, FALSE);

    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
        L"WindowClass",
        L"Our First Direct3D Program",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        300,
        300,
        wr.right - wr.left,
        wr.bottom - wr.top,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

    // set up and initialize Direct3D
    InitD3D(hWnd);

    // enter the main loop:

    MSG msg;

    while (TRUE)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);

            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                break;
        }

        RenderFrame();
    }

    // clean up DirectX and COM
    CleanD3D();

    return msg.wParam;
}


// this is the main message handler for the program
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    } break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}


// this function initializes and prepares Direct3D for use
void InitD3D(HWND hWnd)
{
    // create a struct to hold information about the swap chain
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC scd;

    // clear out the struct for use
    ZeroMemory(&scd, sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));

    // fill the swap chain description struct
    scd.BufferCount = 1;                                   // one back buffer
    scd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;    // use 32-bit color
    scd.BufferDesc.Width = SCREEN_WIDTH;                   // set the back buffer width
    scd.BufferDesc.Height = SCREEN_HEIGHT;                 // set the back buffer height
    scd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;     // how swap chain is to be used
    scd.OutputWindow = hWnd;                               // the window to be used
    scd.SampleDesc.Count = 4;                              // how many multisamples
    scd.Windowed = TRUE;                                   // windowed/full-screen mode
    scd.Flags = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH;    // allow full-screen switching

    // create a device, device context and swap chain using the information in the scd struct
    D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
        &scd,
        &swapchain,
        &dev,
        NULL,
        &devcon);


    // get the address of the back buffer
    ID3D11Texture2D* pBackBuffer;
    swapchain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&pBackBuffer);

    // use the back buffer address to create the render target
    dev->CreateRenderTargetView(pBackBuffer, NULL, &backbuffer);
    pBackBuffer->Release();

    // set the render target as the back buffer
    devcon->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &backbuffer, pDepthBuffer);


    // Set the viewport
    D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport;
    ZeroMemory(&viewport, sizeof(D3D11_VIEWPORT));

    viewport.TopLeftX = 0;
    viewport.TopLeftY = 0;
    viewport.Width = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    viewport.Height = SCREEN_HEIGHT;

    devcon->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);

    InitPipeline();
    InitGraphics();
}


// this is the function used to render a single frame
void RenderFrame(void)
{
    // update WVP matrices
    ConstantBuffer cb;
    cb.mWorld = XMMatrixTranspose(g_World);
    cb.mView = XMMatrixTranspose(g_View);
    cb.mProjection = XMMatrixTranspose(g_Projection);
    devcon->UpdateSubresource(wvpConstBuffer, 0, NULL, &cb, 0, 0);

    // clear the back buffer to a deep blue and the depth buffer
    devcon->ClearRenderTargetView(backbuffer, D3DXCOLOR(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    devcon->ClearDepthStencilView(pDepthBuffer, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH | D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL, 1.0f, 0);

    // select which vertex buffer to display
    UINT stride = sizeof(VERTEX);
    UINT offset = 0;
    devcon->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &pVBuffer, &stride, &offset);
    devcon->IASetIndexBuffer(pIBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);

    // select which primtive type we are using
    devcon->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D10_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

    // draw the vertex buffer to the back buffer
    devcon->DrawIndexed(3, 0, 0);

    // switch the back buffer and the front buffer
    swapchain->Present(0, 0);
}


// this is the function that cleans up Direct3D and COM
void CleanD3D(void)
{
    swapchain->SetFullscreenState(FALSE, NULL);    // switch to windowed mode

    // close and release all existing COM objects
    pLayout->Release();
    pVS->Release();
    pPS->Release();
    pVBuffer->Release();
    swapchain->Release();
    backbuffer->Release();
    dev->Release();
    devcon->Release();
}

void InitDepthBuffer()
{
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC td;
    ZeroMemory(&td, sizeof(D3D11_TEXTURE1D_DESC));
    td.Width = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    td.Height = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    td.MipLevels = 1;
    td.ArraySize = 1;
    td.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    td.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
    td.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;

    ID3D11Texture2D* depthStencilTexture;
    dev->CreateTexture2D(&td, NULL, &depthStencilTexture);

    D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC dsvDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&dsvDesc, sizeof(D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC));
    dsvDesc.Format = td.Format;
    dsvDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2DMS;
    dev->CreateDepthStencilView(depthStencilTexture, &dsvDesc, &pDepthBuffer);
    depthStencilTexture->Release();
}

// this is the function that creates the shape to render
void InitGraphics()
{
    // create a triangle using the VERTEX struct
    VERTEX OurVertices[] =
    {
        {-0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, D3DXCOLOR(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)},
        {0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, D3DXCOLOR(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)},
        {0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, D3DXCOLOR(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)},
    };


    // create the vertex buffer
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd;
    ZeroMemory(&bd, sizeof(bd));

    bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;                // write access access by CPU and GPU
    bd.ByteWidth = sizeof(OurVertices);             // size is the VERTEX struct * 3
    bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;       // use as a vertex buffer
    bd.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;    // allow CPU to write in buffer

    dev->CreateBuffer(&bd, NULL, &pVBuffer);       // create the buffer


    // copy the vertices into the buffer
    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE ms;
    devcon->Map(pVBuffer, NULL, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, NULL, &ms);    // map the buffer
    memcpy(ms.pData, OurVertices, sizeof(OurVertices));                 // copy the data
    devcon->Unmap(pVBuffer, NULL);                                      // unmap the buffer

    unsigned int indices[] =
    {
        0, 1, 2,
    };

    // indices
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bdIndices;
    bdIndices.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bdIndices.ByteWidth = sizeof(indices);
    bdIndices.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
    bdIndices.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    bdIndices.MiscFlags = 0;
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData;
    InitData.pSysMem = indices;
    InitData.SysMemPitch = 0;
    InitData.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;
    dev->CreateBuffer(&bdIndices, &InitData, &pIBuffer);

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bdWVP;
    ZeroMemory(&bdWVP, sizeof(D3D11_BUFFER_DESC));
    bdWVP.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bdWVP.ByteWidth = sizeof(ConstantBuffer);
    bdWVP.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
    bdWVP.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    dev->CreateBuffer(&bdWVP, NULL, &wvpConstBuffer);

    g_World = XMMatrixIdentity();

    XMVECTOR Eye = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, -5.0f, 0.0f);
    XMVECTOR At = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    XMVECTOR Up = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    g_View = XMMatrixLookAtLH(Eye, At, Up);

    g_Projection = XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(XM_PIDIV2, SCREEN_WIDTH / (FLOAT)SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0.01f, 100.0f);
}


// this function loads and prepares the shaders
void InitPipeline()
{
    // load and compile the two shaders
    ID3D10Blob* VS, * PS;
    D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"shaders.shader", 0, 0, "VShader", "vs_4_0", 0, 0, 0, &VS, 0, 0);
    D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"shaders.shader", 0, 0, "PShader", "ps_4_0", 0, 0, 0, &PS, 0, 0);

    // encapsulate both shaders into shader objects
    dev->CreateVertexShader(VS->GetBufferPointer(), VS->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &pVS);
    dev->CreatePixelShader(PS->GetBufferPointer(), PS->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &pPS);

    // set the shader objects
    devcon->VSSetShader(pVS, 0, 0);
    devcon->PSSetShader(pPS, 0, 0);

    // create the input layout object
    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC ied[] =
    {
        {"POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
        {"COLOR", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
    };

    dev->CreateInputLayout(ied, 2, VS->GetBufferPointer(), VS->GetBufferSize(), &pLayout);
    devcon->IASetInputLayout(pLayout);
}
```

*shaders.shader*

```
cbuffer ConstantBuffer : register(b0)
{
    matrix World;
    matrix View;
    matrix Projection;
}

struct VS_OUTPUT
{
    float4 Pos : SV_POSITION;
    float4 Color : COLOR0;
};

VS_OUTPUT VShader(float4 Pos : POSITION, float4 Color : COLOR)
{
    VS_OUTPUT output = (VS_OUTPUT)0;
    output.Pos = mul(Pos, World);
    output.Pos = mul(output.Pos, View);
    output.Pos = mul(output.Pos, Projection);
    output.Color = Color;
    return output;
}


float4 PShader(VS_OUTPUT input) : SV_Target
{
    return input.Color;
}
```

Пока я не добавил матрицы, всё работало.

Comment: Собственно я вчера уже все написал: **начните проверять ошибки**, выключите culling, выключите тест глубины, начните с добавления одной матрицы и обязательно со значением identity. Поставьте точку останова в шейдер и убедитесь, что значение в константном буфере передалось.

Comment: Я прочитал документацию по UpdateSubresource, и там не говорится, как вычислять ошибки выполнения этого метода. А где именно поставить точку останова в шейдере?

Comment: @user7860670 я поставил брекпоинт в шейдере. Вот результат https://imgur.com/bqIUMx5. Пишет, что дело до этого брекпоинта ещё не дошло, как я понял.

Comment: UpdateSubresource не возвращает ошибки немедленно, там нечего проверять, зато в других местах - очень даже. Шейдеры отлаживаются постмортем, см https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50591937/how-do-i-launch-the-hlsl-debugger-in-visual-studio-2017/50592268

Comment: @user7860670 когда я ставлю флаг D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG и пытаюсь запустить программу в режиме отладки, я получаю ошибку Unhandled exception. Но, впрочем, я выяснил, что если в вершинном шейдере не задействовать матрицы, а просто оставить строку `output.Pos = Pos;`, то всё заработает. Это означает что либо, как вы уже говорили, не передаются константные данные в шейдер, либо из-за неправильно указанных в матрицах вершинных данных треугольник «отбрасывается».  Я проверял HRESULT каждого метода, связанного с константными буферами — всё работает правильно.

Comment: @user7860670 день ломал голову и понял, что не указал `VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &wvpConstBuffer);`. Спасибо вам за приложенное время.